# Error en el auto-reinicio de pm2: el puerto ya esta siendo usado

Tags: nodejs, pm2

He estado usando pm2 para hacer que mi api en nodeJS corra permanentemente y se inicie con el sistema. Había estado funcionando correctamente, pero recientemente, cada vez que pm2 reinicia el api, en los logs de pm2 se muestra el siguiente error:

```
Conexión a base de datos realizada correctamente...
{ Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3800
```

Y debo cambiar el puerto desde mi index.js para que se reinicie correctamente. Esto hace que también deba cambiar la dirección de peticiones de mi Angular front-end. Intenté tumbar el api con "pm2 stop" e iniciarla de nuevo con "pm2 start" e incluso borré el proceso de la lista de pm2 con "pm2 delete", pero el problema persiste y sigo teniendo que modificar mi index.js

¿Cómo evito tener que modificar mi código cada que se reinicia?

La primera vez que me sucedió fue cuando la conexión a mongoDB en la nube se perdió por un corto momento.

Comment: Hola BU_PC, te sugiero revisar que aplicación esta usando ese puerto con `netstat -nptl` y terminar ese proceso y así podrías identificar que esta sucediendo, con ese comando obtendrás el numero de proceso

Comment: El comando anterior es para Linux, en windows es:  `netstat -a -o -n`

Comment: Gracias a @JhoubertRincon por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he resuelto. Dejaré una respuesta por si le sirve a alguien.

Usando `netstat -a -o -n` descubrí que, por algún motivo que desconozco, si había una aplicación usando el mismo puerto (lo cual me parece raro, pues había estado usando ese puerto sin problemas). Detuve esos procesos usando `taskkill /PID <no. de PID de la app> /F` y problema resuelto.